# Angular material menu click doesn't have effect just in case media query

Tags: angular, media-queries, angular-material

I'm having a stragnge behaviour while I'm trying to work with angular material menu component while doing Media Query.

I have a custom media query, I'll render some html according to its response.

Firstly, I have a menu item. When page reloads, it's fine to open menu by clicking large and small buttons. After that when I click out of the menu panel, it disappears as expected. However, when I resize the window to trigger media query matches and click large or small buttons, menu item opens, but doesn't close when I click out of it in the page.

To be it more clear I have added a button called ordinary to test the unexpected behaviour and realized that this strange behaviour doesn't seem on that button.

It's quite complex, because of that I have created a stachblitz page for that.

Just press the button, you will see a menu item will be rendered and click out of the menu panel, it will disappear. Than resize the window so media query will be triggered and large or small buttons will don't have any effect to close the menu.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qswyoq

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work if you enter the zone:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3eb7q?file=src/app/app.component.ts

My guess is that because the click handler after media change is bound outside of the zone, the menu is initialized outside of the zone and the event used to close the menu does not trigger the change detection.